# Analyzing an Integral Involving a Complex Function with Symmetry Properties: approximation or simplification

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, approximation, harmonic-analysis, signal-processing

I am exploring the properties of an integral expression involving a complex function `f(θ)`, which is defined over the interval `[0, 2π]`. The function `f(θ)` is unique in that its real part is even, and its imaginary part is odd. The integral expression I am examining is:

$$
\frac{\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\theta) \theta^k d\theta}{\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\theta) d\theta}
$$

Given the symmetrical properties of `f(θ)`, I am interested in two main aspects:

1. **Proving the Result is Real:** Given the even real part and odd imaginary part of `f(θ)`, how can we show analytically that the integral yields a real number?
2. **Simplification Using Symmetry:** Is it possible to simplify the calculation by halving the domain of integration due to the symmetrical properties of `f(θ)`?

I understand that the even nature of the real part and the odd nature of the imaginary part should provide some pathway to simplification or at least to a clearer understanding of the integral's behavior. However, I'm not entirely sure how to apply these symmetries effectively to this specific integral expression.

Could anyone offer insights or techniques for leveraging the symmetries of `f(θ)` to simplify or analyze this integral? Any advice on how to proceed or references to similar problems would be greatly appreciated.

#### Context:

- I've encountered this problem while working on an analysis involving complex functions and their integration over periodic intervals.
- The specific properties of `f(θ)` (even real part and odd imaginary part) were identified through preliminary analysis and are key to understanding the behavior of the integral.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or guidance you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Given $f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ you can always divide the function as
$$
f(\theta)=\mathcal{Re}(f)(\theta)+i \mathcal{Im}(f)(\theta)
$$
The two functions are real function than
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta) d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\mathcal{Re}(f)(\theta)d\theta + i\int_0^{2\pi} \mathcal{Im}(f)(\theta) d\theta
$$
Anyway there is no reason for the function to be real. As if i take *e.g* $f(\theta)= 1+i \theta$  than your integral is not real. Moreover you can't halve the domain of integration as your domain of integration is not symmetric.

If your domain of integration is given by $[-\pi, \pi]$ than the function is real and you can halve the domain of integration